# How to create a dynamic form helper based on database tables?

Tags: cakephp, helper

Using cakephp 2.3.0
The conditions for the helper are:
1) I need to use many drop down boxes in multiple forms and I don't want to do loadModel in each and every controllers(12)
2) Need to fetch the datas from database tables
3) I am thinking of not baking files for the tables.
4) Want to use custom mysql queries.

E.g I've a table named countries and the dropdown should be key=>abbreviated name and name=>full name.

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function in helper
`

```
public function getDropDownList($table,$key,$value)
    {
        //$db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
        $fields = $key.','.$value;
        $CommercialHeaders =& ClassRegistry::init('tablename');
        $sql = $CommercialHeaders->query('select '.$fields.' from '.$table.' as DropDown');
        foreach($sql as $val)
        {
            $countryList[$val['DropDown'][$key]] = $val['DropDown'][$value];    

        }
        //debug($countryList);
        return $countryList;    
    }
```

`
and just called it from the view by passing table name and field, which will generate an array so it solves my problem without setting it in appcontroller or using requestAction